# Content in scroll view is shifted down with height value of navigation menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I use view controller with embedded in navigation controller.

In this view I added scroll view and then content view inside scroll view

I added constrains for scroll view - zero for top, bottom, leading, and trailing. And the same for content view - zero for top, bottom, leading, and trailing. 
And I added width and height for content view the same as main view.

Inside content view I need to add different content (labels, text fields, buttons) - this will be settings screen with vertical scroll.

Now I see that content is always shifted down a bit (the same value as menu height)

How to make to located vertically on top?

And how to put all the content in the content view that should be vertically long and scrollable vertically?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you forget to remove tick -> Adjust scrollview insects .

[image]

Comment: Damn those insects!

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line to the `viewDidload` method of your ViewController.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you attribute inspector setting in Storyboard.Uncheck

> adjustScrollViewInsets

from viewcontroller storyboard.Viewcontroller Storyboard settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to storyboard and select the appropriate viewcontroller and Uncheck AutomaticallyadjustScrollviewInsets.

Or

Go to viewdidload
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

Answer (score 0):

Go to your viewcontroller `viewDidLoad` method put following code.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 11, `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is deprecated and adjusting `UIScrollView`'s `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` is recommended instead.

This worked for me pretty well (Swift):

```swift
scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
```